# Delay execution of a function until completion of another using jQuery when method

Tags: javascript, jquery, .when

I am trying to delay the execution of a jQuery function from the [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) plugin until another function (which replaces the target html id) is completed using jQuery when method. However, the following script doesn't seem to do it right.

The idea is that to let the loadxml() function finishes populating the HTML tree then execute the jstree() function to apply the treeview.

Here is the HTML

```
      <div id="jstree" class= "col-md-6 col-xs-6"></div>
```

the script

```
          $.when(loadxml()).then(function(){

                 $('#jstree').jstree();

           });



function loadxml(){

$.ajax({

    url: "xml/categories.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(catxml){
        var categories = new Array();
        var outputDisplay = "";

        $(catxml).find("Categories").each( function(){
            var cid = $(this).find("CategoryID").text();
            var cname = $(this).find("CategoryName").text();
            var cdescription = $(this).find("Description").text();

            categories.push([cid,cname,cdescription]); 
        }); 

        $.ajax({
            url: "xml/products.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(prodxml){

                var products = new Array();

                $(prodxml).find("Products").each(function(){
                    var pid = $(this).find("ProductID").text();
                    var pname = $(this).find("ProductName").text();
                    var pcatid = $(this).find("CategoryID").text();
                    var pquantity = $(this).find("QuantityPerUnit").text();
                    var pprice = $(this).find("UnitPrice").text();

                    products.push([pid,pname,pcatid,pquantity,pprice]);                     
                });            

                outputDisplay += "<ol class='no-bullet'><li>Product List<ol type='i'>"

                for(i=0; i<categories.length; i++){

                    outputDisplay += "<li>" + categories[i][1] + "<ol type='a'>";

                    for(x=0; x<products.length; x++){

                        if(categories[i][0] == products[x][2]){

                            outputDisplay += "<li>" + products[x][1] + "</li>";                            

                        }

                    }

                    outputDisplay +="</ol></li>";

                }

                document.getElementById("jstree").innerHTML = outputDisplay;


            }
       });




    }    
});
```

}

Comment: Your `loadXML` function needs to `return` a promise, otherwise `when` doesn't know what to wait for!

Comment: Also you should be using `then` instead of `success`, otherwise it can't know about the second ajax request (and won't wait for it either).

Comment: Call 2nd ajax (products.xml) from `success` of the 1st and `.tree()` from success of the 2nd.

Comment: Hi Alex, I already tried calling it from success of the 2nd with no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Promises:

```
loadxml().then(function() { 
    $('#jstree').jstree(); 
});

function loadxml(){

  return $.ajax({/* parameters */})
          .then(function(catxml) {
             //code that runs on the result of the first ajax request

             //return the promise from the next ajax request
             return $.ajax({/* parameters */})
           })
           .then(function(prodxml) {
               //code that runs on the result of the second ajax request
           });
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for this. I couldn't get this to work. Not sure why, I tried both using .then and also then but both instances but didn't work for me.

Comment: Two things? What about it `didn't work` - did you get an error? Did your `jstree` run before your requests were finished? Secondly, what's your version of jQuery? If it's <= 1.7.x you may have to use `.pipe` in replace of `.then`

Comment: Hi Adam, I've figured what was causing it to not work. It was to do with where I was declaring my variables. I made them global variables. Technically it should work. However, I believe due to the jstree function your suggested code stuck at loading

Answer (score -1):

deffered

```
        $.when(loadxml()).then(function(){

             $('#jstree').jstree();

       });



function loadxml(){
var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
     success : function(){
        //code
        $.ajax({

          success: function(){
             //your code
             deferred.resolve();

          } 
        })
     }
  })

   return deferred.promise(); 


}
```

});

Comment: Antipattern - just return the promise, you don't need a new deferred object.

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry could you break down what are meant to do here instead? sorry I am not an expert in JS and Jquery

Comment: @user3608262 - ilyass's answer will work, but using `$.Deferred` objects when not required is an antipattern and should be avoided in favour of more readable code - e.g. use the promise returned by the `$.ajax` call instead of creating a new and unnecessary one.